# Php e guzzle, como fazer um get para um endereço e pegar o que retornar?

Tags: php, return, guzzle

Estou precisando enviar dados por get e pegar o que retornar para saber se deu certo ou não, porem, com cURL e file_get_contents não esta dando(parece ser coisa do servidor que recebe a requisição), dai estou tentando usar o Guzzle, fiz um teste aqui e parece não ter dado problemas, porem, não sei bem como ver o retorno da requisição, estou fazendo assim:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\Response;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->get('http://www.endereco.com.br?dados');
var_dump($response->getBody());
```

Ele imprime isso na minha tela:

> object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#24 (7) {
>     ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
>     resource(5) of type (stream)
>     ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
>     NULL
>     ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
>     string(10) "php://temp"
>     ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
>     array(0) {
>     }
>   }

Tem como pegar o HTML ou json com a resposta do servidor ?!

Vlw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correta a resposta do @RodrigoRigotti.

Há também uma outra maneira de converter os dados, que é utilizando o método mágico `__toString`.

Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
$body = (string) $response->getBody();
```

Ou assim:

```
$body = $response->getBody()->__toString();
```

Particularmente, eu prefiro a primeira forma.

Se quer debugar um objeto que pode ser convertido para string através do `var_dump`, você deveria fazer assim:

```
var_dump((string) $response->getBody());
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta passar `true` como parâmetro do método `Response::getBody()` para receber o corpo do HTML como string.

```
$html = $response->getBody(true);
```